# MySQL DB says i have no permission to access it through Android Studio project

Tags: java, android, mysql, sql, android-studio

I'm trying to connect to a MySQL DB inside an Android Studio project and i keep getting an error that im denied access, i tried a normal Java program and it was fine but with Android it won't.

This is the error:
`java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'Hadi.mynet' (using password: YES)`

And this the code for connecting:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
                    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.108/menu","root","root");
                } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException throwables) {
                    throwables.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read: [JDBC vs Web Service for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15853367/295004)

Comment: how can you access it directly without a password? An error is saying that `Access denied for user 'root'@'Hadi.mynet' (using password: YES)` means you have to add password also to access your database.